# Jquery: show/hide div on hover. Show on click

Tags: jquery, mouseover, show, jquery-hover, mouseleave

Let's assume I have a div with a `.description` class.

I would like `div.description` to be shown when user hovers over another div, with the `.image` class.

However, when user clicks on `div.image`, I would like `div.description` to stay visible. So if user clicks on `.image`, the `mouseleave` event should not be applied.

Lastly, when user clicks on the `.image` again, the hover function should be activated again. So that when mouse leaves `.image1`, `div.description` will be hidden again.

Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: what have you tired, show your code

Comment: What would be easier than 'saying' all this, is seeing actual HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var cancel = false;
$(".another").hover(function(){
    $("div.description").show();
},function(){
  if(!cancel)
  $("div.description").hide();
});

$(".image").click(function(){
  cancel = (cancel)?false: true;
});
```

Comment: Touch screen devices have no hover function, so you might want to call **$("div.description").show()" inside your click function if cancel is true.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this: http://jqversion.com/#!/CCvqpwh

```
$('.image').bind('mouseenter', function(){
    $('.description').show();
}).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    $('.description').hide();
}).click(function(){
  if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    $(this).unbind('mouseleave');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).bind('mouseleave', function(){
        $('.description').hide();
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind two events to same elements like bellow.And use separate function to get what your want

```
var myFunction1 = function() {
   $('div.description').show();
}
var myFunction2 = function() {
  // do whatever you want
}
$('div.image')
    .click(myFunction1)
    .mouseover(myFunction2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this script

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.overlay').hide();
    });
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.element, .element-1').hover(function() {
            jQuery('.overlay').show();
            },
        function() {
            jQuery('.overlay').hide();
            });
    });
```